# Difference between Interop Outlook and Outlook Object Library

Tags: .net, visual-studio, outlook, office-interop

I have a question about visual studio, I noticed when you add references in the COM section you can find: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0 Object Library. While on the Assemblies you can see the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

I would like to know the difference between this two, I tried researching but i have only found topics on each one of those but not the differences, I would love if somebody could provide me with an explanation, Juts simple curiosity. (I'm kind of a beginner). Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a good question.  Do you find the "Object Library" on the COM tab?  Sounds like a COM vs COM wrapper to me.. but I don't do much Office development.

Comment: I think one's the title and one's the file name...

Comment: The Office Object library references found under the COM tab allow you to use `Embed Interop Types` and that way, you don't have to ship any DLL files with your program. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24530231/8967612) for more info.

Comment: Interop Outlook you manage the instance, it's not a managed library by .NET CLR, you have to dispose by yourself but another one is .Net Managed, means all instance you create .NET will collect garbage.... Etc.. there's many other differences i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both pretty much the same - when you reference OOM from the COM tab, VS under the covers creates an interop dll (which is essentially nothing  but a header file in a binary format). That is the same interop dll that you can add to your project as a reference.

The biggest advantage of adding a reference to an interop dll instead of the COM library itself is the ability to build the project even if the COM library is not installed, e.g.on a dedicated builder machine, which might not have Office installed.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Office will still need to be installed on the target machine though. Shipping the dll file(s) isn't enough.

Comment: To run - yes. To compile- no, you don't need to have Outlook installed *if* you ae referencing the interop dll only.